# Excel check if same value exist across all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file which has 82 sheets in it, all sheets have the same title in column A but on Column B has different status, think of it as a task name on column A and its status on Column B.

I want to check if the status of task on Column `A5` is same across all sheets or how many times the status is *critical* and how many times status is *ok*

If I was using a single sheet I know the following formula would give how many tasks have critical status on the same sheet

`=COUNTIF(B5:B24,"critical")`

But I want to check how many times `B5` has status *critical* across all sheets, how can i do this?

Any assistance will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can use the UDF mentioned in the link above to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

This code iterates through all the sheets, and creates a formula that sums up all the `countif`s

Then, it stores the formula in `A1`

```
s = ""
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
 s = s & "+COUNTIF(" & Sheets(i).Name & "!B5:B24,""critical"")"
Next
range("a1")=s
```